# Create a collection of item ids Revit API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, collections, set, ironpython, revit-api

So I am trying to use a list of input strings to isolate them in a view using Revit API. I got this far, but I am getting stuck where I am trying to create a set that takes all elements in a view and removes ones that are created from input IDs. I am doing this to end up with a set of all elements except ones that i want to isolate.

```
dataEnteringNode = IN0
view = IN0
str_ids = IN1
doc = __doc__
collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc, view.Id)

for i in str_ids:
    int_id = int(i)
    id = ElementId(int_id)
    element = doc.GetElement(id)
    element_set = ElementSet()
    element_set.Insert(element)

elements_to_hide = collector.WhereElementIsNotElementType().Excluding(element_set).ToElements()

#Assign your output to the OUT variable
OUT = elements_to_hide
```

I would greatly appreciate a help in solving this error. I am getting that "expected ICollection[ElementId], got set". I am guessing the problem lies in a Excluding filter where i need to create a collection of Ids to exclude but I dont know how. Thank you in advance. Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Which line caused the error? And I think `element_set` should be declared outside the loop, not inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that `ElementSet` in the Revit API does not implement the `ICollection<T>` interface - just the `IEnumerable<T>`. So, to get your code working, you will need to create an `ICollection<T>` object from your set.

Try something like this:

```
# ...
from System.Collections.Generic import List
element_collection = List[ElementId](element_set)
elements_to_hide = collector.WhereElementIsNotElementType().Excluding(element_collection).ToElements()
```